# Using Linq to see if any one subrecord has a sepcific value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a set of tables that are linked using foreign keys like so

```
A 1----* B
```

That is, A can have many B records.

I need to add a "where" clause to return all of the A records where B.isMax == true if a certain flag is passed in to my function. I'm not sure how to handle this.

```
public List<A> GetA(int AID, string AName, bool? isActive, bool? isMax)
    {
        var q = from a in Context.A
                select a;

        if (AID > 0)
        {
            q = q.Where(c => c.AID == AID);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AName))
        {
            q = q.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(AName));
        }

        if (isActive != null)
        {
            q = q.Where(c => c.IsActive == isActive);
        }

        if (isMax != null)
        {
            // ???? Can't do this. How can I implement this kind of thing??
            q = q.Where(c => c.B.IsMax == isMax);
        }

        List<A> ret = q.ToList();

        return ret;
    }
```

Any thoughts??

Comment: It can be either `Any` as the answers suggested, or `All` - depending on your requirements. Also, when you reference a nested collection, it would probably be recommended to do `q = q.Include("B").Where(c => c.Any/All(x => x.IsMax == isMax))` to avoid N+1 problem further along the way. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx):

```
q = q.Where(c => c.B.Any(i => i.IsMax == isMax));
```

`Any` is used to check whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `Any`?

```
q = q.Where(c => c.B.Any(b => b.IsMax == isMax));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you think, is this good idea do something like this?

```
public List<A> GetA(int AID, string AName, bool? isActive, bool? isMax)
{
    return Context.A
            .Where(c =>
                       (AID <= 0 || c.AID == AID)
                    && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AName) || c.Name.Contains(AName))
                    && (isActive == null || c.IsActive == isActive)
                    && (isMax == null || c.B.Any(b => IsMax == isMax))
                  )
            .ToList();
}
```